# How to copy instances of a custom defined class in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to copy instances of a custom class in Python 3.3, similar to how `dict.copy()` and `list.copy()` work. How do I go about this?

Here is an example of my custom class:

```
class CustomClass(object): # Custom class example
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
```

Comment: Can you use [`copy.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/copy.html#copy.copy)?

Comment: Um...it probably didn't work so well. Test: `copy.copy(CustomClass) is CustomClass`. The answer is `True`. I.e., no copy was made. It's handing you back the same object.

Comment: @JonathanEunice What I used was `object = CustomClass('foo')` and then on the next line `new_copy = copy.copy(object)`. This makes a copy of the variable, which is what I wanted. For example, if I use that and then write `object.thing = 'bar'`, `new_copy.thing` remains `'foo'`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, you can use the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to produce copies of Python objects.

- `copy.copy()` will produce a *shallow* copy; a new instance is created but all attributes are simply copied over. If any of your attributes are mutable and you mutate those objects you'll see those changes reflected on both objects.
- `copy.deepcopy()` will produce a copy recursively; any mutable objects will themselves be cloned.

If your class implements a `__copy__` method it'll be used to create a shallow copy of the object; return a new instance with attributes copied over and altered as needed.

Similarly, you can implement a `__deepcopy__` method to implement a custom deep copy method; it'll be passed the `memo` state, pass this on to recursive `copy.deepcopy()` calls.

Note that you cannot use this to copy a *class object* however. Classes are meant to be *singletons*; you don't need to create a copy in that case. You can use *subclassing* instead, or a class factory function, to produce distinct class objects.

Comment: Very true in general. But when the object in question is a class, no bueno. Even `copy.deepcopy(CustomClass) is CustomClass`. I.e., no copy is made. It's handing you back the same object.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: that's because classes are meant to be singletons.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: use subclassing if you need distinct classes.

Comment: Exactly. Therefore, copies are not possible. The OP asked for a copy of a class. They can copy instances, but they cannot copy classes.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: I think the OP is being imprecise about vocabulary here. There is an `__init__` with a sample instance attribute; I think they are creating copies of instances here.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. If it's instances they want to copy, the `copy` module is dead-on.

Comment: @JonathanEunice: you have confirmation in the comments on the question; this is about instances.

Comment: @MartijnPieters question edited to reflect that it is instances, not classes, that are being copied.